# Windows Server 2008 Web vs Standard

Tags: windows-server-2008, database, scalability, scaling, web-farm

Please tell me what choice will be best between Windows Server 2008 R2 Web edition and Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard edition for NoSQLDatabase/BackendComputing scaling farm? I am pretty sure that there are can be 30-100 servers in net. What reasons can be for choose Standard edition instead Web edition? Which of these editions can be nice as frontend server? And could you tell me please: is standard edition may replace web edition, in another words, is standard edition can be choice by default if i do not know which of editions to choose?

Thank you for any advice!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web edition does not require client CALs and would be the preferred OS on the Microsoft side for web hosting.  It has many limitations compared to Standard edition but if the purpose is to run a public facing web farm, then it is the right choice.

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/r2-compare-specs.aspx

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/r2-differentiated-features.aspx

For virtual environments you'd normally license the servers with Datacenter editon per processor but I haven't looked into running a bunch of web editions on that platform from a licensing perspective.

Answer (score 1):

The Web edition is a cut price version of Windows Server for Web hosting companies to make Windows Server less uncompetitive compared to Linux web hosting.  It has a reduced feature set. I have tried to find a feature comparison on the microsoft website, but they are too busy trying to flog you Windows Server 2008 to tell you about the 2003 versions.

You may be able to use the Web Edition, but expect to run into unsupported feature issues, and be pleasantly surprised if it works