# Windows Server 2008 Web vs Standard

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, scalability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Server 2008 Web vs Standard](https://serverfault.com/questions/204357/windows-server-2008-web-vs-standard)

Please tell me what choice will be best between Windows Server 2008 R2 Web edition and Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard edition for NoSQLDatabase/BackendComputing scaling farm? I am pretty sure that there are can be 30-100 servers in net. What reasons can be for choose Standard edition instead Web edition? Which of these editions can be nice as frontend server? And could you tell me please: is standard edition may replace web edition, in another words, is standard edition can be choice by default if i do not know which of editions to choose?

Thank you for any advice!!!

Comment: I suggest that before yo use ANY kind of server operating system that you consult the appropriate documentation to determine suitability for YOUR purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the suppliers of your database platform are the best people to answer the question. They will know what their platform will work well with, though I wouldn't be surprised to hear the answer was "Standard Edition".

You may find [this chart](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/r2-compare-roles.aspx) from Microsoft comparing their different server editions to be useful

Answer (score -1):

Windows HPC Server 2008*, the next generation of high-performance computing (HPC), provides enterprise-class tools for a highly productive HPC environment. Windows HPC Server 2008 can efficiently scale to thousands of processing cores and includes management consoles that help you to proactively monitor and maintain system health and stability. Job scheduling interoperability and flexibility enables integration between Windows and Linux based HPC platforms, and supports batch and service oriented application (SOA) workloads.

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/r2-editions-overview.aspx

Comment: Doesn't answer or help towards answering the question.